# Pentaho Design Studio - Blank report - warning Invalid chunk

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I created a simple xaction with jdbc connection.The action was successful but am getting a blank report.

Resultset is not shown up.

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<action-sequence> 
<title>latest1</title>
<version>1</version>
<logging-level>TRACE</logging-level>
<documentation> 
<author>reskin</author>  
<description>Empty blank action sequence document</description>  
<help/>  
<result-type>none</result-type>  
<icon/> 
</documentation>

<inputs/>

<outputs> 
<resultset type="result-set" is-output-parameter="false"> 
<destinations> 
<response>resultset</response> 
</destinations> 
</resultset> 
</outputs>

<resources/>

<actions> 
<action-definition> 
  <component-name>SQLLookupRule</component-name>
  <action-type>Relational</action-type>
  <action-outputs> 
    <query-result type="result-set" mapping="resultset"/> 
  </action-outputs>
  <component-definition> 
    <query><![CDATA[select * from cust_txn_list]]></query>  
    <live><![CDATA[true]]></live>  
    <driver><![CDATA[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]]></driver>  
    <connection><![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive_sample]]></connection>  
    <user-id><![CDATA[root]]></user-id>  
    <password><![CDATA[553450]]></password> 
  </component-definition> 
 </action-definition>

</actions> 
</action-sequence>
```

I am getting the following warning message in BI Server log

```
Parameters: Invalid chunk '' ignored. is the warning
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved.The problem was due to the ouput paramater,"is output parameter checkbox should be checked always.